# VB .net datetimepicker reporting wrong value

Tags: vb.net, dialog, datetimepicker

Ok, so I'm experiencing some strange behavior in datetimepicker fields in my program.  I use Short format usually, and use a pair of them for date range selections.

The problem i'm experiencing is if a user is using the keyboard for input.  they can tab and arrow through the field like normal to key in a date.  However if the date part they are entering doesn't fill it's section of the mask and then they press enter to activate the formdefault without shifting focus away from that portion of the date, then the value of the DTP when the ok_button.click event is run is whatever value it had in it BEFORE they typed their change.

to give a specific example:

A user tabs into the date field.  the default date in the field is today's date, 4/14/2015.  They type in 1, arrow to the day, put in 1, then arrow to the year and type 14, then press enter.  The reported value of the DTP is going to be 1/1/2015.  Had they instead actually typed out 2015, or used the arrow to move to another date part or tab to shift focus to another control, the DTP will auto update to fill in the rest of the year.

The same problem would exist if they had typed in a 1 for the month and then hit enter, but would NOT happen if they put in a 12 for the month.

The only solution I can think of, and I haven't yet tried to implement it because it sounds like a real kludge and would require me to go through at TON of forms in the project, would be to change the keypress event for enter to shift focus to the OK button, and THEN invoke the formdefault.
I will say that most of the datetimepicker fields on my forms are actually contained within a user control, so if this is a property that can be changed in the control or tied to an event in the control, it would make updating much, MUCH easier.

Comment: *...type in 1, arrow to the day, put in 1, then arrow to the year and type 14, then press enter* the date value is `1/1/2014` on mine.  do you already have some key handlers going?

Comment: I call the forms like so:

Comment: I call the forms like so: 
`
frm = new form1
if frm.dialogresult = windows.forms.dialogresult.cancel then
 frm = nothing
end if
exit sub
'

within every form, the OK_button event does all of it's processing, and then the last two statements are 
`
me.dialogresult = system.windows.forms.dialogresult.ok
me.close()
'

Then each form has an AcceptButton property set to the OK_button, and CancelButton set to the Cancel_Button so the user can use Enter to click ok, or ESC to get out of the form.

Comment: Still no repro.  When I hit enter, the DTP changes 1/1/14 into a proper date 1/1/2014 and that is what is gotten back from the Dialog.

Comment: A bit late, but I have a similar problem.  My issue is reading the value while the DateTimePicker still has a field focused.  Losing focus causes it to update the value to reflect a partially entered field (for example, turns 1 into 01), but until focus is lost it returns the value it had before gaining focus.